# Getting xml response from web service

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I'm trying to get answer from web service in asp.net that return

```
<GetDataFieldsResult>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml
</GetDataFieldsResult>
```

I call the web service

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('webserviceaddress');
$result = $client->GetDataFields();

$response_result = $result->GetDataFieldsResult;
```

I have another function in what web service that return string and I can display (echo / echo var_dump) response result from web service.

But with this function I don't get any response or data.

How can I read the result from this function which return

```
<GetDataFieldsResult>
     <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml
</GetDataFieldsResult>
```

Edit:
Did as Grzegorz pointed out use `$client->__getFunctions()` and `$client->__getTypes()`. To check correct method as it is.

One thing I notice with $client->__getTypes was this

```
[22]=> string(63) "struct GetDataFieldsResult { schema; any; }"
```

But other functions which return string has this

```
[5]=> string(45) "struct LoginResponse { string LoginResult; }"
```

So how to get data which have schema; any; I have no problem getting string LoginResult;

Then I use try-catch, I do not get any exceptions.

Comment: Use `$client->__getFunctions();` and `$client->__getTypes();` to check if you use correct method.
Do you get exceptions when you use try-catch?

Comment: with your edit this is getting more clear. Can you also please show what `var_dump($result)` gives (*after* you've obtained it from the service ;))

Comment: When I use `var_dump($result)` the browser start downloading file. Filename is download and it is empty.

Comment: Then use: `header('Content-Type: text/plain;');  var_dump($result); die();` - this should prevent the download. If that does not help, request not with your browser but with curl on the commandline. (sorry for late response)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did try that but same happens, get downloaded a file.

Comment: I have not tried curl on commandline but I tried SoupUI for testing and found out that the response is around 49MB in size and response time is to slow more then 4 min. Is it possible that size limit are the cause of this problem?